# Creating a Backbone Plugin (catering for AMD/Require.js)

Tags: backbone.js

I have a couple of backbone overrites such as

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.validate = function(data) {...}
```

that are working well in my project. I want to export them into a new file so that they can be used by other projects if needed. I'm not sure how to go about this and I'm not sure if I should wrap them in define.

Any help on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you look at the [UMD (Universal Module Definition) project](https://github.com/umdjs/umd), which aims to provide conventions for defining javascript modules that work in the browser as well as in most common script loaders.

In order to support RequireJS (AMD) as well as browser globals, you might want to look specifically UMD's [AMD/web](https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/master/amdWeb.js) syntax.

Here is an example of a Backbone-dependent mediator module, which works with or without RequireJS:

```
(function (root, factory) { return typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['backbone'], factory) : (root.mediator = factory(root.Backbone)); }(this,
    function (Backbone) {

    var events = Backbone.Events;

    /**
     * Mediator provides a decoupled communication mechanism.
     * Borrows the implementation from Backbone.
     */
    return {

        //expose the on/off/trigger for native Backbone listenTo/stopListening support.
        on:             events.on,
        off:            events.off,
        trigger:        events.trigger,

        //expose subscribe/unsubsribe/publish aliases for idiomatic mediator pattern interface
        subscribe:      events.on,
        unsubscribe:    events.off,
        publish:        events.trigger
    };
}));
```

I typically squish the module declaration to a single line of code as in above, but see UMD's AMD/web-sample for a commented version of the same.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have all your roles for all your models in a file (`libs/validation/rules`).

If you're already using something like require.js:

```
// model/user.js
define([
      'libs/validation/rules'    
], function(ValidationRules) {

    return Backbone.Model.extend({
        validate: Validation.User  
    })
})
```

Else, you can export your validation rules using a global object (bad idea, but it works) :

```
// model/user.js
Backbone.Model.extend({
    validate: window.Validation.User  
})
```

Comment: the purpose of using prototype is so that I don't have to create the validate function if every model. I can set it once and that's it.

Comment: Yes, you're right, and in my example it's the same, `validate` is defined on the prototype too :)